# Create a vector of mean substituted values based on another vector

Tags: r, pandas

In my line of work it is not uncommon to have a continuous vector that needs to be 'discretized'. What I want to do is replace the values of a continuous variable that has been discretized by `cut` with the mean of another variable over those cut ranges.

**EDIT**

Furthermore, the mean (or whatever other function I want to use to generate a value) must be based on the original data and applied to new data. Imagine the situation where I calculate mean bad rates for a continuous variable on a training data set, build a model and then have to apply that same transformation logic to new data.

**END EDIT**

Consider the following data:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
x.disc <- cut(x, c(-Inf, -2, 0, 2, Inf))
lookup <- aggregate(x, list(x.disc), mean)

> lookup
    Group.1          x
1 (-Inf,-2] -2.2322429
2    (-2,0] -0.6968720
3     (0,2]  0.8671428
4  (2, Inf]  2.6696064
```

What I would like to do is create a new vector, x1, where the value is equal to the x value in lookup when the original x values fall in the corresponding range. My expected output vector would look like this:

```
> head(x)
[1] -0.1867972  1.7309683 -0.1306331  1.2787303  0.8388222 -0.4449465
```

Desired Output:

```
> head(x1)
[1] -0.6968720  0.8671428 -0.6968720  0.8671428  0.8671428 -0.6968720
```

In `pandas` for `python` there is a group-by-apply paradigm that uses `transform` to broadcast the aggregated values back to the same dimension as the input. Is there something similar for `R`? I would like to keep it to base functions for my understanding but am not opposed to using other packages.

Comment: Are you just wanting `ave(x, x.disc, FUN=mean)` ? (so no use of a lookup)

Comment: Or may be  `lookup$x[match( x.disc, lookup$Group.1)]`

Comment: yes, thank you for the suggestions. I should clarify (and will do so in an edit) that I need to be able to apply whatever transformation I devise to new data. So I have to save the lookup information somehow so I can use it later.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
   x.disc <- cut(x, c(-Inf, -2, 0, 2, Inf), labels=FALSE)
   lookup <- aggregate(x, list(x.disc), mean)
   lookup$x[x.disc]
```